# SQL Server 2008 database engine login failed for administrator user in windows 7

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I installed SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition on Windows 7 Ultimate from sadegh user.

This account exists in administrators role. after a few days I removed sadegh user from Windows and now I am using administrator user. But I can't login to SQL Server database engine using Windows authentication method and I receive this error message:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to SADEGH-PC.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Login failed for user
>   'Sadegh-PC\Administrator'. (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 18456)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

please help me! thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Depending on what mode SQL Server was installed (Windows Authentication or Mixed Mode), you may have to do a few things. If you installed in mixed mode, you can log in as sa and add the administrator user as a Login under the Security section. Make sure you assign sysadmin role to the user, which can be found under Server Roles.

If Windows Authentication mode was chosen during install then there are a couple of things you can do, but I think the easiest is just to recreate the user sadegh, login into SQL Server as that user, and follow the previous step to add the administrator user as a login.

**UPDATE:** If all else fails, you can run SQL Server in Single User Mode, which allows a single connection to the server, and enable/change the sa password. To do this you can:

1. Open the command prompt (Right-Click on and select "Run As Administrator")
2. From the command prompt type **net stop MSSQLSERVER**
3. Next type **net start MSSQLSERVER /m**
4. Open SQL Server Management Studio. Do not login, cancel the login dialog.
5. From the file Menu select New->Database engine query, and login (Make sure you use the host name and not localhost).
6. Execute the query **ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '';** to reset the password (if the sa is not enabled then type **ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE** to do so)
7. Login with the sa user and add the Administrator user.

**EDIT:**

As indicated by @jimasp in the comments, for step 6 you may have to do **ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '' UNLOCK;**, because the sa account may be locked from too many login attempts.

Tested on Windows 7 Ultimate with SQL Server 2008 Standard. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks i created Sadegh user and try that but i still can't login with this account also!

Comment: oh! my god! i forgot my password for sa! :')

Comment: oh man! very very very thank's! ;)

Comment: Wtf, how are you suppose to login to SQL Server Management to fix the login to SQL Server management. This doesn't make sense Garett. I cannot do step 5, and I am using the correct hostname.

Comment: @Dexter. This definitely works. I've tested it myself, and clearly it worked for @Sadegh. The key is to get the server running in single user mode where only one connection is allowed. You can also do it using `sqlcmd`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx

Comment: @Garett, I understand now to use sqlcmd. When I used it, I was able to get in using your steps. However, after I did alter login sa. I am still unable to connect to SQL Management Server Studio using Windows authentication OR SQL authentication. So these steps did not help me.

Comment: I also had to use the unlock option: 
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = 'yourpass' UNLOCK;
due to too many login attempts with the sa password.

Comment: @jimasp Good point! I'll add your comments to the answer.

Comment: @Garett - How do you do step 5? I am unsure what "host" would be be. I am sort of in the same boat as Dexter.

Comment: @chobo2 By hostname I'm referring to the name of your machine as opposed to using localhost. You can get the hostname by typing "hostname" in a command prompt.

Comment: Ah ok I tried that before but it won't let me connected says login failed. I get this 2012-01-17 11:17:45.39 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11.
2012-01-17 11:17:45.39 Logon       Login failed for user 'MyAccount'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: @chobo2 I just tried it on SQL Server 2008 R2, and was able get in using hostname or (local). What OS are you on? Have you looked into the error? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/c3e0713c-b4e6-400e-9ba2-448cd5bf3cb8

Comment: @Garett - Here is my post it will give you more info - http://serverfault.com/questions/350759/cant-connect-to-local-database

Comment: Step 7 kept failing for me. I found that the DB instance was set to Windows Authentication Only. I had to add my windows account (DOMAIN\USERNAME) instead of the sa account in step 6.

Answer (score 5):

In previous versions of SQL the BUILTIN\Administrators group was given the sysadmin role. Local administrators are not given login privileges by default in SQL 2008. Only the user performing the install is defaulted sa privileges. During install you have the option to add additional users, but you apparently did not.

You will need to login as sa and configure whatever windows logins are required (such as the local administrator account).

Answer (score 2):

If don't want to use SQL Server Management Studio and you can login as the user who installed SQL server, try this from a command prompt:

```
OSQL -S <insert_servername_here> -E
1> EXEC sp_password NULL, ‘<insert_new_password_here>’, ‘sa’
2> GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting this error was due to the same connection being opened multiple times but it never being closed and such the connection pool was maxed out.

In short, check your closing all your connections.