# How to use Windows Authentication with SSMS without using RunAs?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2012 installed as a standalone instance in Windows 8 Enterprise edition.  It is running in Mixed-mode.  The currently logged in account is a member of local MACHINE\Administrators and the local BUILTIN\Administrators group is in the sysadmin role.  For good measure, the current user is also in a MACHINE\SQLAdmins group which is also in the sysadmin role.

When I launch SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) from the shortcut, I can't use Windows Authentication.  I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
Cannot connect to INSTANCENAME.
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Login failed for user 'MACHINE\user'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476
```

In fact, if I launch LinqPad from a shortcut, I can't connect to the server using a connection string which relies on Windows Authentication.

However, if I run SSMS or LinqPad with elevated privileges using RunAs Administrator, I can use Windows Authentication and the experience is as expected.

Alternatively, I can include the RunAs command into the SSMS shortcut like so.

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /USER:MACHINE\user "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

Surprisingly, double-clicking the shortcut will prompt for me to enter the password of the current user.  However, once that re-authentication occurs, SSMS will allow Windows Authentication of the current user.

The question is, what user is SSMS running under when I double click the shortcut and ultimately, how can I just run LinqPad or SSMS or any other app that connects to the database with Windows Authentication without first elevating my privileges?

Comment: Did you add the user account to the `sysadmin` role, or just the `machine\administrators` group?  If the later, you are only a member of that group when you're elevated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance supplying the credentials of the user who installed SQL Server when you use `Run as`?

See the second answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833373/sql-server-2008-database-engine-login-failed-for-administrator-user-in-windows-7):

> In previous versions of SQL the BUILTIN\Administrators group was given
>   the sysadmin role. Local administrators are not given login privileges
>   by default in SQL 2008. Only the user performing the install is
>   defaulted sa privileges. During install you have the option to add
>   additional users, but you apparently did not.
>
> You will need to login as sa and configure whatever windows logins are
>   required (such as the local administrator account).

I had the same thing happen, where my user account was a local admin, and yet unable to login until the guy who installed SQL Server added my windows account to the SQL Server logins manually.

Comment: Before I posted this question I reinstalled and added MACHINE\Administrators during the install.  Yes the RunAs user did the install, but I also created the MACHINE\SQLAdmins post install and added that group with sysadmin role.  The install user is in MACHINE\SQLAdmins yet still has to RunAs to use Windows Auth.

Comment: Is there anything in the error logs that might give you a clue?

Comment: Login failed for user 'MACHINE\User'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: <local machine>]  I am not seeing relevant previous error. (FYI: I am running in VMware)

Comment: Never seen that issue, but some quick Googling points at UAC perhaps being the culprit:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/10/27/troubleshooting-specific-login-failed-error-messages.aspx

and 

http://www.sqldbops.com/2010/05/token-based-server-access-validation.html

Comment: It does seem to be UAC. Adding the user directly to the logins as a sysadmin rather than as a group member fixes the problem. Of course RunAs admin and I presume disabling UAC also works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of SQL the BUILTIN\Administrators group was given the sysadmin role. Local administrators are not given login privileges by default in SQL 2008. Only the user performing the install is defaulted sa privileges. During install you have the option to add additional users, but you apparently did not.